# Implementing a simple gaussian naive bayes algorithm in python

Tags: python

So im a real amateur, trying to implement something you may call a sort of 'simplified' version of the naive bayes algorithm in python, and seem to have a lot of trouble [the reason for which is perhaps the fact that im not too sure i completely understand the way the algorithm works..]. I would appreciate any help/suggestions very much though. This is the code I have:

```
class GaussianNB(object):

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        # This variable will hold the gaussian distribution over your data
        # In fact, you need a distribution per class for each feature variable.
        # This can be done as a list of lists.

        self.classmodels_count = {}
        self.classmodels = {}
        self.classmodelsMeanAndVariance = {}
        self.featureTokenCount= 0;
        self.featureTypeCount = 0;

    def train(self, trainingdata):
        for i in trainingdata:
            current_class = i[0]
            features = i[1]

            if self.classmodels.has_key(current_class):
                current_class_model = self.classmodels[current_class]
                self.classmodels_count[current_class] =  self.classmodels_count[current_class] + 1
            else:
                current_class_model = {}
                self.classmodels_count[current_class]  = 1

            for f in  features:
                feature = f[0]
                value = f[1]
                if current_class_model.has_key(feature):
                    list_of_values = current_class_model[feature]
                    list_of_values.append(value)
                    current_class_model[feature] = list_of_values
                else:
                    list_of_values = []
                    list_of_values.append(value)
                    current_class_model[feature] = list_of_values

            self.classmodels[current_class] = current_class_model
        for a_class in self.classmodels.keys():
            a_class_model = self.classmodels[a_class]
            a_class_model_mean_and_variance = {}
            for feature in a_class_model.keys():
                a_class_model_mean_and_variance[feature] = findMeanSD(np.array(a_class_model[feature]))
            self.classmodelsMeanAndVariance[a_class] = a_class_model_mean_and_variance

    def classify(self, testing_vecs):
        outputs = []
        for vec in testing_vecs:
            features = vec[1]
            class_model_output_prob = {}
            for a_class in self.classmodelsMeanAndVariance.keys():
                a_class_output_prob = 0.0
                a_class_model_mean_and_variance = self.classmodelsMeanAndVariance[a_class]
                for feature_value in features:
                    feature = feature_value[0]
                    value = feature_value[1]
                    #simply ignore a feature if its not seen in training
                    if(a_class_model_mean_and_variance.has_key(feature)):
                        feature_mean = a_class_model_mean_and_variance[feature][0]
                        feature_std = a_class_model_mean_and_variance[feature][1]
                        a_class_output_prob = a_class_output_prob +  math.log10(norm(value,feature_mean,feature_std))

                #ignoring P(class) prior.. assuming equal priors
                class_model_output_prob[a_class_output_prob] = a_class
            probs = class_model_output_prob.keys()
            print probs
            probs.sort()
            max_prob = probs[len(probs)-1]
            max_class =class_model_output_prob[max_prob]
            outputs.append(max_class)
        return outputs
```

When running on some data, the error I get is

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\workspace\Assignment6\src\gnb_test.py", line 34, in 
    gaussian = Model.train(testData)
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\workspace\Assignment6\src\gnb.py", line 91, in train
    for f in  features:
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

And I dont really [at all] understand what it means

Comment: so what problems are you having?

Comment: What's your question? Could you narrow your code,  and explain what are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback suggests that the problem is that you are trying to iterate through `features`, but `features` is a float and not a list or tuple - basically, it can't be broken into individual elements. I think it is a float because the lines

```
for i in trainingdata:
   current_class = i[0]
   features = i[1]
```

suggest `features` keeps getting rewritten as a successive series of numbers, when what you seem to want is to save the numbers into an iterable type. Try

```
features = []
for i in trainingdata:
   current_class = i[0]
   features.append(i[1])
```

Comment: thanks! doesnt work either though, now I get:

feature = f[0]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: Is a sample element from your list of lists that is your trainingdata of the form [class_id, feature_name, value] (as in, this is the form that every row of your data takes)? If so, features = [f[1] for f in trainingdata] to get the list of all features and then you can iterate over it. Your second error suggests that I misinterpreted your question and you still have features as an un-iterable type.